# Python not getting new values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i've been trying to do a forum post scraper for a website. And i am struggling to get new posts using python. So far i've tried this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r

HTML1 = r.get('https://www.brick-hill.com/forum/2').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML1, 'html.parser')
Title=soup.span.get_text()
print(Title)


OldVar = Title
TitleNew=soup.span.get_text()

while Title != OldVar:
    print(TitleNew.)
```

It's supposed to detect when the text changes to print it to the console (or set it as a var) how do i fix this?

**EDIT:** I changed the code to print out... but still i have problems.

Answer (score 0):

the code below will always trigger the return statement. You are setting the OldVar to Title before the condition evaluation but after you updated the title variable. Also in the snippet you posted there is no console output.

```
OldVar = Title

if Title == OldVar:
    return
```

Comment: I tried making it print, but still nothing. what i want to know is how can i check if the value changed... and if so print the new one.

Comment: post the code that includes the print call, and also are you sure that get post is being called at all?